# Category whose morphisms are commutative monoids but not enriched

Tags: ct.category-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

In a recent investigation, I constructed a category $\mathcal{C}$ with the following property. For objects $X,Y \in \mathcal{C}$, the morphism set $\text{Mor}(X,Y)$ is a commutative monoid with addition denote by $+$. However, $\mathcal{C}$ is not **CMon** enriched, where **CMon** is the monoidal category of commutative monoids. The reason is that $+$ is not distributive w.r.t. the composition of morphisms.

My question is whether there is a name for such a category and is there any study for such a category?

I am interested in looking at functors into $\mathcal{C}$ such that the monoid structures of morphism sets are preserved. I really appreciate any answer.

Comment: I guess the specific example you came across is too specialised to describe here — but can you give some “toy example” of such a situation?

Comment: Roughly speaking (not very precise), an object $X$ is a measurable space. $\text{Mor}(X,Y)$ are like random variables which can be added. Compositions are defined in a more involved way but the key point is that they are not distributive w.r.t. the addition. To study relations with other categories with similar structures, I want to look at functors that preserve the monoid structure. I would like to know if there is already some theory on such categories.

Comment: Any category can be endowed with such a structure since any set can be made a commutative monoid.

Comment: @FernandoMuro Or at least -- any nonempty set!

Comment: @TimCampion ooooops…

Comment: @FJ: Since you have a concrete category in mind, to provide a meaningful answer you really need to spell out the details of your category.  It is not possible to gather what kind of structure you have just from the vague descriptions we have so far.

Comment: @FJ: in your example(s), does composition preserve addition on one side, but not both? Or does it not preserve addition on either side?